# CSS menu style different on home page versus internal page?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I semm to be having an issue where the custom font I'm using within the website's navigation looks fine on every single page EXCEPT the home page.

I have absolutely no idea what the issue is, as the CSS should be global and why it's behaving differently based on URL is beyond me.

Hover over the top navigation here (where all links look fine): http://store-4pduo2f.mybigcommerce.com/chairs-and-stools/

Now do the same here (links look strange) : http://store-4pduo2f.mybigcommerce.com/

Any help would be awesome thanks!

Comment: have you included the same set of CSS for both the pages ?

Comment: I don't even see the difference? Which one of the menus?